# Call block from inside block

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-c we have declared a completion block that acts as a callback for web requests.

If the request fails then I would like to be able to call the function again, from within the completion block. When I do this I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` due to the block not being fully defined.

This is annoying because in Java I can do this with listeners.

Is it possible to call a completion block from within?

Thanks.

The following code throws the error, how could I fix this please?

```
CustomErrorBlock errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {

    _processing = NO;
    loadingView.hidden = YES;

    self.infoText.hidden = NO;
    self.infoText.text = @"A network connection error has occurred.";
};


CustomCompletionBlock completionBlock = ^(NSData *data){

    if(![self processGetTransactions:data withDict:updateDict]) {

        [webClient getTransactions:updateDict WithCompletionBlock:completionBlock andErrorBlock:errorBlock];
    }
};
[webClient getTransactions:updateDict WithCompletionBlock:completionBlock andErrorBlock:errorBlock];
```

Comment: Can you post all the function.

Comment: Do you copy completionBlock?

Comment: How do you mean copy?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to stop the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash by using __block which tells compiler it must be treated in a special way and also __weak which makes the object not retain strong.

```
__block CustomErrorBlock errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {

    _processing = NO;
    loadingView.hidden = YES;

    self.infoText.hidden = NO;
    self.infoText.text = @"A network connection error has occurred.";
};


__block CustomCompletionBlock completionBlock = ^(NSData *data) {

    if(![self processGetTransactions:data withDict:updateDict]) {
        __weak CustomCompletionBlock weakCompletionBlock = completionBlock; // Note seems to always have retain cycle

        [webClient getTransactions:updateDict WithCompletionBlock:weakCompletionBlock andErrorBlock:errorBlock];
    }
};

    [webClient getTransactions:updateDict WithCompletionBlock:completionBlock andErrorBlock:errorBlock];
```

Note: weak object still displays a message about object being strong for some reason but it sill works without any problems.